# Google Cloud Storage - options for upload/download

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

What are people's recommendations for working with Google Cloud Storage (GCS) for applications served by the browser - both upload and subsequent download/stream of video? Particular in a primarily  GCP PaaS based environment

My current environment is a React JS Single Page Application (SPA) served by Firebase hosting. The SPA currently communicates with NodeJS Express backends that are served by Google App Engine (GAE)

Ideally I would use Express with a combination of the Multer module and Google Storage API's on the backend - however GAE has a 32Mb limit for requests and the file uploads are expected to be larger than this limit.

For this environment I'd like to PaaS as much as possible and whilst I'm a big fan of Kubernetes/Container environments I'm trying to leverage as much 'turn key' solutions from GCP as much.

Look forward to hearing people's opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the clients a signed url so they can talk directly to GCS rather than going through your app: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls